# Хранение пароля php

Tags: пароль

Есть задача.

У нас подключены разные платежки на сайте. К некоторым из них для доступа к API нужен пароль/ключ, которые содержатся в базе/файлах. Необходимо выдать доступ некоторым кодерам, но таким образом, чтобы они никак не смогли получить доступ к этим данным.

Создать файл в отдельной папке, а им предоставить доступ к другой — не катит. Они смогут его прочитать при помощи PHP.

Как быть?

Comment: `Необходимо выдать доступ` и `не смогли получить доступ` - Не понятно.  Они `смогут его прочитать при помощи PHP.` - Кто такие они? По-точнее с подробностями задайте свой вопрос.

Comment: Другие специалисты, у которых будет доступ для выполнения определенных работ. Их нужно выдать таким образом, чтобы данные к платежкам они увидеть никак не смогли

Comment: Ну так не давайте доступ к базе. А дайте их только схему базы, на крайняк база с "демо" данными.

Comment: У него будут исполняемые php файлы, которые подключены к базе. Что мешает ему SQL запросом вытащить пароль из неё?

Comment: вы в открытом виде пароли храните чтоли?

Comment: Как вам уже сказали, вы не можете выдать доступ так, чтобы люди не получили доступ. Если вы не доверяете этим разработчикам, пусть выполняют свою работу абстрактно и/или на тестовых данных. Кто ж допускает до боевых сервисов аутсорсников?

Answer (score 0):

Если секрет можно взять из кода, то можно считать, что его может взять кодер этого кода.

Можно только попытаться стоять у кодера за спиной проверять и психологически воздействовать. А инвесторам рассказывать, что всё под контролем.

Если говорить о техническом решении, то можно попытаться разделить код, который работает с секретами, и код, который делает полезные, но не несущие большие риски вещи.

Например: 2 группы кодеров, 2 микросервиса на 2-х серверах,
которые будут посылать друг-другу запросы и т. п.

Всё это их взаимодействие нужно будет описывать, проверяя на потенциальные новые проблемы безопасности.

Куча работы, но уж если надо...